# Losing DataAnnotations when using POCO Entity Framework 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, data-annotations, poco

I'm using the new EntityFramework 4.1 with POCO objects, in conjunction with the DataAnnotation framework.

When EntityFramework needs to create a proxy class (for example, lazy loading virtual properties), all of my data annotations are lost. Is there some way that my ModelMetaData can come from the class that was proxied, instead of the proxy class?

I know that I have the choice to disable proxy creating (`context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled`) but this seems like a poor answer. This should be something that's been solved, I would think.

Here's some example code:

```
public class Person
{
    [Required, Display(Name = "Display That Name")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

And then in my model metadata in the view, the type is: `Person_9C92B92D56F6F4F0FB1686526D585438A05323CC72E457C2152796E8866297E1 (FullName = "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Person_9C92B92D56F6F4F0FB1686526D585438A05323CC72E457C2152796E8866297E1"})`, my metadata is gone, and the displayname renders out at "DisplayName" not "Display That Name".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out one possible solution. Not sure if there are better ones. First I wrote a new ModelMetadataProvider:

```
public class IgnoreProxiesDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider : System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        modelType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(modelType);
        containerType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(containerType);

        return base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
    }
}
```

And then registered it in Global.asax application start:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new IgnoreProxiesDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();
```

If there's a better solution, please let me know!

Comment: To determine if a type is proxied its a 'little' easier to use ObjectContext.GetObjectType.

Answer (score 6):

You could make a Metadata version of your model classes.
We do that thisway...  what EF generate is never touched by hand.

Let said you have a Person class:

```
public partial class Person
{
        public int idPerson { get; set; }
        public int idTenant { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could make the Metadata class, that holds the metadata and won't be overrided:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PersonMD))]
    public partial class Person
    {
       //leave it empty
    }

    public partial class PersonMD
    {
       [Required]
       public int idPerson { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public int idTenant { get; set; }

       [Required, Display(Name = "Display That Name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What we do is as follows:

Modify the T4 templates to generate partial classes for your entities.

For those entities that you wish to add annotations to, create a partial class of the same name of your entity.

Create a buddy class within this class that provides your annotation details.

Apply the attribute at the top of the partial class to specify that your buddy class is where the annotation details can be found.

See here for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141.aspx